# How do I swap 4 values in Python?

Tags: python

My lab is asking me to take four integers and swap the first value with the second and the third with the fourth. I have been able to make this work with the following code when the input is 4 integers, however when the function is called as an input nothing is returned. Can anyone help?

```
def swap_values(int1, int2, int3, int4):
    new1 = int2
    new2 = int1
    new3 = int4
    new4 = int3
    line = str(new1) + ' ' + str(new2) + ' ' + str(new3) + ' ' + str(new4)
    return line
  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    start1 = input()
    start2 = input()
    start3 = input()
    start4 = input()
    answer = swap_values(start1, start2, start3, start4)
    print(answer)
```

Comment: What does it mean `when the function is called as an input` ??

Comment: Works fine, input `A`/`B`/`C`/`D`, output: `B A D C`

Comment: What does the lab mean by swap? The function cannot change the values of immutable input paramters. You would have to return the values and assign them

Comment: To swap a and b: `a,b = b,a`.

Comment: Why not do `A, B, C, D = B, A, D, C`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you call input and nothing happens:

```py
def swap_values(int1, int2, int3, int4):
    line = str(int2) + ' ' + str(int1) + ' ' + str(int4) + ' ' + str(int3)
    return line
  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    start1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    start2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    start3 = input("Enter third number: ")
    start4 = input("Enter fourth number: ")
    answer = swap_values(start1, start2, start3, start4)
    print(answer)
```

input waits for the user input in the terminal, you can also add a prompt.

You also don't need the new variables.

make sure that you don't have to swap values this way:

```py
val_a = "A"
val_b = "B"

temp = val_a
val_a = val_b
val_b = temp

print(val_a) # B
print(val_b) # A
```

Comment: Well, you also don't really need the function ;)